# Reporting on Workflows in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, shared-libraries, sharepoint-designer, shared-hosting

Is there a way to create a report in SharePoint where i can view all my current workflows and the status of each workflow?

**Edit:** I need to be able to have a List or something where i can view all my Workflows with the status and so on in my SharePoint site.

Answer (score 2):

There is some basic reporting built in. Check out this article;

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101646711033.aspx

You can also get some overview of custom workflows available using this tool in Codeplex;

http://spworkflowstarter.codeplex.com/